# Visual Studio no longer connecting to Power BI Premium

Tags: visual-studio, powerbi

I have a tabular model in VS that I set up per the instruction below and have successful deployed it to Power BI Premium multiple times. Yesterday I made some changes and tried to deploy but am getting an error:  An error occurred while connecting to the server.   When I deployed in the past it would open up the Microsoft Pick an Account window before proceeding with the deployment. That is no longer happening, which I assume is what is creating this connection issue.

I have restarted VS, restarted the server, recreated the connection configuration and changed my domain password, but all to no avail.

Anyone had this problem or have any ideas on how to get it to resume prompting me to chose my account to connect with?

Thank in advance.

[Error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbmAj.png)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/deployment/deploy-from-visual-studio-tabular
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-premium-connect-tools#deploy-model-projects-from-visual-studio-ssdt

Comment: What version of Visual Studio? If you go to help… About Microsoft Visual Studio what do you see as the version of Analysis Services Projects? I would also go to see if there are updates for the Analysis Services Projects extension in VS. I’m guessing this is related to some out of date client libraries in an old version of the extensions but hopefully the above can help us determine that.

Comment: This is what it looks like: 

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 
Version 15.9.31
VisualStudio.15.Release/15.9.31+28307.1342
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.03761

Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2017

ProjectServicesPackage Extension   1.0
ProjectServicesPackage Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

SQL Server Analysis Services   15.0.19623.0
Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services Designer 
Version 15.0.19623.0

SQL Server Data Tools   15.1.62002.01090
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

Analysis Services Projects version: 2.9.18

Comment: Sorry that formatting looks so terrible.

Comment: @GregGalloway - In hopes that it might help, I uninstalled Analysis Services Projects  and readded it to VS.  But that didn't help unfortunately. Still not prompting to connect to MS online and still giving the connection error on deployment.

Comment: try changing the ADAL Cache property to None in the project properties for your visual studio project. That seems to cause an annoying amount of authentication pop ups. Incidentally I can’t reproduce your problem with the same version of Visual Studio and Analysis Services extension deploying to Power BI Premium Gen2. What’s the “server name” you are trying to deploy to? Hopefully it starts with powerbi:// ?

Comment: @GregGalloway - I changed the ADAL property to None with no luck.   The server is set to powerbi://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/**********

Comment: hmm. I assume that workspace is still on premium capacity (it has a diamond icon) and reports on it are working fine. The only problem is you can’t deploy a new report? Do you see build errors in the output window? Do a Build on the project and then go to View… Output and choose Build from the drop down at the top of the Output window.

Comment: Can you also try using the Analysis Services Deployment Wizard after a successful build?

Comment: @GregGalloway So I had one of my coworkers try it and it deployed properly for them. I was hoping that would fix it for me, but no luck.

Comment: @GregGalloway When I try Analysis Services Deployment Wizard I get this error. 
"Unable to connect to powerbi://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/***** : The connection string is not valid."

This is the error on in VS:
"------ Build started: Project: K***** , Configuration: PowerBI x86 ------
Error: An error occurred while connecting to the server.
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped =========="

Comment: @GregGalloway Thanks for you help, your troubleshooting helped me narrow it down.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.   I restarted the server, then used a service account to log into the server and followed the below directions to delete my widows profile.  Then when I tried to deploy it prompted me to choose which account to sign in with and deployed as expected.

https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/tutorial-how-to-delete-user-profile-in-windows-10.html